How to reset ball position if it goes out of bounds, using p5.js and matter.js?
I want to reset the ball back to its initial position if it flies off the screen, or if its position.y < 0 (I'll add in other boundary conditions once this is figured out).
I tried simulating that by removing the ball if it flies off (because I couldn't find a way to reset the position).
But that doesn't remove the circle even though other elements stop colliding with it. It only freezes the circle, which I think is a p5 issue.
Also the test console.log statement I have, logging the y coordinate, keeps infinitely logging a y-coordinate.
CODE:
This is the Ball class.
import Matter from 'matter-js'

export default class Ball {
    constructor(x, y, r, world) {
        this.body = Matter.Bodies.circle(x, y, r);
        Matter.World.add(world, this.body);
        this.r = r;
    }

    show(p) {
        const pos = this.body.position;
        const angle = this.body.angle;
        p.push();
        p.translate(pos.x, pos.y);
        p.rotate(angle);
        p.rectMode(p.CENTER);
        p.fill("white");
        p.strokeWeight(0);
        p.circle(0, 0, this.r);
        p.pop();
    }
}

This is the final App component where everything gets rendered:
    import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import p5 from 'p5';
import Matter from 'matter-js'
import './App.css'
import Ball from "./components/Ball.jsx";
import Boundary from "./components/Boundary.jsx";

let Engine = Matter.Engine;
let World = Matter.World;
let Mouse = Matter.Mouse;
let MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;
let ground, box, ball, world, engine, mCon, leftWall, rightWall;

function sketch(p) {
    p.setup = function() {
        const canvas = p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
        engine = Engine.create();
        world = engine.world;

        const canvasMouse = Mouse.create(canvas.elt);
        canvasMouse.pixelRatio = p.pixelDensity();
        const options = {
            mouse: canvasMouse,
        }
        mCon = MouseConstraint.create(engine, options);

        ground = new Boundary(p.width/2, p.height-10, p.width, 20, world);
        leftWall = new Boundary(10, p.height/2, 20, p.height, world);
        rightWall = new Boundary(p.width - 10, p.height/2, 20, p.height, world);
        ball = new Ball(50, p.height - 100, 25, world);

        World.add(world, [mCon,
        ]);
    }

    p.windowResized = function() {
        p.resizeCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
    }

    p.draw = function () {
        p.background(51);
        Engine.update(engine);
        rightWall.show(p);
        leftWall.show(p);
        ground.show(p);
        ball.show(p);

        if (ball.body.position.y < 0) {
            console.log(ball.body.position.y);
            World.remove(world, ball.body);
        }
    }
}

function App() {
    const p5Container = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const p5Instance = new p5(sketch, p5Container.current);

        return() => {
            p5Instance.remove();
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div ref={p5Container} className="container">
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

DEMONSTRATION OF ERROR
You can see the white ball stuck at the top unaffected by gravity, and y position continuously being logged.

How do I go about solving this problem?

You're removing the Matter.js body from the MJS world, but your Ball instance still exists, as does its .body property, which still references the MJS body. This body still exists in a detached state and can still be drawn with P5. With World.remove(), you've taken it out of the simulation, but not the visualization--the two are out of sync.
Instead of World.remove(world, ball.body); try Matter.Body.setPosition(ball.body, 50, p.height - 100) to move it back to its origin, if that's your goal. You may also want to use setAngle, setVelocity and setSpeed to set default values on the body.
It's also possible to remove the ball as you're doing and add a new one back at its origin, the same way you created the old one:
this.body = Matter.Bodies.circle(x, y, r);
Matter.World.add(world, this.body);

This would probably be a method in the Ball class, and you may need to make x and y properties on this., like this.originalX, this.originalY, so you can refer to them outside the constructor.
As an aside, World is deprecated and replaced by Matter.Composite.

No problem--you want to ease or lerp the transition? You can use setPosition repeatedly in the draw loop until it reaches the origin.

Thanks a ton! This helps a lot... I'm trying to setPosition instead of removing and adding, but that sets the position from it's previous "out of screen" position, which means it flies back really fast from that "out of screen position" to initial position. That looks a bit jarring. Should I just switch to my previous idea of removing and adding a new object, or is there a way to make it simply respawn in the original position?

setPosition should be instantaneous. Don't use updateVelocity on it and be sure to zero out the other properties. But sure, it's a two-liner to remove and add, worth a try.

how do I create a sort of time gap between that happening though? I want to use the setPosition method (resetting the position) for both, when the ball goes offScreen or when it hits one of the static boxes on the scene (modified the code above to include that). But it happening immediately feels jarring.

I'd go back to my first comment. If it doesn't make sense, feel free to open a new question with your current code and I'll see if I can add an answer. For context, what sort of game are you making? If you don't care about the physics when resetting, you can pause MJS and simply animate it with a traditional P5 lerping or easing animation, then unpause MJS once things are reset and you want to run it again.

I'll look into it, thanks a ton!

Please open a new question, because if you modify the code here to integrate my answer, then it'll be confusing for future visitors. I'll roll back your edit but feel free to open a new question.
